# Insert instead of update in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert new values into Firebase Realtime Database. But every time I "register" a new user, my database data is getting replaced by the new one. I'm totally confused on how I can do this different.

This is my code..

```
//Create a new user with txtfield email & password
     Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in

     //Printing error if any
     if error != nil
     {
     print(error as Any)
     return
     }

     //Getting database reference
     let ref = Database.database().reference()

     //Values to insert into database
        let values = ["Username": self.username, "Email": self.email, "Name1": self.name1, "Name2": self.name2, "Name3": self.name3, "Name4": self.name4, "Name5": self.name5, "Name6": self.name6, "Dog1": dog1, "Dog2": dog2, "Dog3": dog3]

     //Updating the child values
     ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in


     //Printing error if any
     if err != nil
     {
     print(err as Any)
     return
     }

     //Succeded if no errors
     print("Saved user successfully in Firebase database!")

     })
```

And I assume the problem is at

```
         ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
```

But I've no idea how I can replace this. So to make it short.
Every time I create a new user, the database data is getting replaced. And I basically want it to create a new "row" for each user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert the items under a child like `users/userID`

```
 guard let firUser = authResult.user else { return }
 let userID = firUser.uid
 let ref = Database.database().reference()
 let user = ref.child("users/\(userID)")
 user.updateChildValues////
```

---

Database

```
  > users

    > njfjnjnf889489489 // some user uid

      > name

      > mail

    > 322jnjnf889489483 // some user uid

      > name

      > mail
```

Comment: From the code I sent you. How can I insert all this values, I'm confused haha

Comment: you should have a structure for your database as `Auth.auth().createUser` is for each user

Comment: Ohhh! I understand! I tried it and now it works perfectly fine, thanks a thousand times!